# JQuery - Why i can't remove a specific cloned form?

Tags: jquery

i want to remove a specific cloned form.

I have one table and a button, and when you click at the button, it clones the table, now i want to remove a specific table cloned before.

I'm trying to do that, but its not working, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Here my code:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <html>
 <head>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(window).load(function(){

   $('.remove').click( function() {
     $(this).parents(".addforms:last").remove();
 event.preventDefault();
    });


  $('.clone').on('click', function(e){
  $(".addforms:last").clone().find("input[type='text']").val('').end().insertBefore($(".addforms:first"));
  event.preventDefault();
  }); 

});

</script>

</head>
 </body>
 <form class='cform' method="POST">
<table border='0' style='background: #1D7373; border-bottom: 1px solid #2e9c9c; color:white; width:100%;'>
    <tr class="addforms">
   <td><input class='txtedit' placeholder='Name' type='text'  name='Name' maxlength='130' /></td>

<td><a class="remove">[X]</a></td>
</tr>
         <input style='width: 60px;' type='submit' class='clone' value='+' />
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to delegate click event, the click handler here is not fired for elements added dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to deal with elements added after window load:

```
$("table").on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".addforms:last").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of:

```
<input style='width: 60px;' type='submit' class='clone' value='+' />
```

Use this: Input time change to **Button**

```
<input style='width: 60px;' type='button' class='clone' value='+' />
```

Complete Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.remove').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents(".addforms:last").remove();

    });


    $('.clone').click(function () {
        $(".addforms:last").clone().find("input[type='text']").val('').end().insertBefore($(".addforms:first"));
    });

});
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/Zh2gA/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Updated my answer take a look